# What is this microwave oven part called?

Tags: microwave-oven

My Panasonic NN-SD945S microwave oven now stops operating after 2-3 seconds.

I think the problem is with the mechanism on the oven's "box" where the door's latch hooks into.  This mechanism somehow registers that the door is properly closed, and transmit this information to the oven's control circuitry.

The part I'm referring to is the one that has number 12 in the diagram shown below.

[image]

I found this figure online, and unfortunately *it does not have a key* <sup>1</sup>.

**Q:  How can I find the name of this part?**

I need this name, first, to see if, by searching for it, I am able to find any guidance online (video, tutorial, etc.) on how to replace it <sup>2</sup>.  And, second, to order the thing.  (I suppose that for the latter, I may need a pretty exact name.)

I suppose the simplest solution to my problem would be to find a version of this diagram that actually has a key <sup>3</sup>.

Alternatively, if someone happens to know what that part is called, please let me know.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>Also, the figure is for a Panasonic model *NN-SD767S* oven, but the part in question is consistent in appearance from what I can see in my model NN-SD945S oven.  More specifically, my oven has two rectangular openings that look very much like the ones in the picture, where the door latch's two hooks insert.</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup> I am now much more aware than before of how important this microwave's door locking mechanism is to its functioning.  With this awareness comes a measure of respect for the prospect of attempting to repair.</sup>

<sup><sup>3</sup> Even better would be to find the version of this diagram for my oven's model (NN-SD945S) *and* with a key.</sup>

Comment: It may not be latching correctly. I had that exact microwave and after the first year, had to take that part and bend it back into proper shape as shutting it over time caused it to bend out of shape. The symptom was similar but also had times where the door needed closed repeatedly to latch.

Comment: Not exactly for that specific model but covers a wide range. https://www.manualslib.com/manual/764833/Panasonic-Microwave-Ovens-With-Inverters.html?page=11#manual

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean: Thank you, that's very useful information!

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean: Though I did not mention it in my post, I believe this part has been defective right out of the box.  More specifically, the button to open the door has always had a tendency to fail, requiring multiple tries before the door opened.  Unfortunately, since I had waited long enough for the oven, I convinced myself that I could live with the defect.  If I had realized then how critical the door latch is to the oven's operation, I would have returned the oven.

Comment: The door latch mechanism has some play with the screws allowing some movement when placing it. It might be as simple as it was not screwed into the exact location needed and simply moving it a millimeter will resolve it.